# Any way to test if java is installed on server?

Tags: java, php, linux

I have a VPS server, and have trouble setting up java.

I wonder, is there any way to test to see if java works?

My VPS server is Linux and I use PuTTY to communicate with the server from my own windows computer.

Thanks

Comment: Tried java --version, whereis java, apropos java, locate java, find / -name java ?

Comment: I can't think of anything other than what you tried...

Comment: Yes, it finds it, but I am troubleshooting my problem. Check out my other Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931720/running-solr-on-vps-problems I cant get Solr working.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? what have you done so far while setting up java? what's the specific problem you're having, what happens when you just type "java" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `java -version` on the VPS server using PuTTY.  If it doesn't recognize the command, you know java either is not installed or not configured properly.

Comment: check out this problem then, because it finds java. But I can't get solr working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931720/running-solr-on-vps-problems